# How to convert seconds to minute and show it right after in label?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need my user to enter the seconds as an input but right after the user enter it I want to convert seconds to minutes and show it to user in label. What am I missing here ?

**View**

```
@Html.BSMaterialTextBoxFor(model => model.seconds, "Enter the seconds",colCSS: "col-6", htmlAttributes: new { data_bindrop = "seconds" , autocomplete = "off" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.secondsStr)
```

**ViewModel**

```
  public int seconds{ get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Time")]
   public string secondsStr
        {
            get
            {
                return (seconds/ 60).ToString() +" Minutes"+ " " + (seconds% 60).ToString()+"Seconds";
            }
        }
```

[image: Next to time , it should write 0 minutes and 45 seconds]

Next to time , it should write 0 minutes and 45 seconds

Comment: What is not working? Is the binding not working?

Comment: what you're missing is details about what exactly _is_ happening and what exactly _should be_ happening.

Comment: after  I enter the seconds all I see is display name of secondStr. Nothing shows up

Comment: Try it like this: `$"{seconds / 60} Minutes {seconds % 60} Seconds"`. That works for me when I set the `seconds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are even easier way to handle what you are trying to achieve.

[image]

Please follow the steps below:

**`Model:`**

```
public class SecondModel
    {
        public double Seconds { get; set; }
    }
```

**`Controller For Display:`**

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {

            ViewBag.Minutes = TempData["Minutes"];
            return View();
           
        }
```

**`Controller When Submit:`**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddSecond(SecondModel second)
        {
            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(second.Seconds);
            string convertedMinutes = string.Format("{0:D2}m:{1:D2}s", t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
            TempData["Minutes"] = convertedMinutes;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Note:** Point to remember in C# or asp.net Core, there is a built in method to do that. I am just using  `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to
implement that.

**`View:`**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.SecondModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form class="form-group" method="post" asp-controller="Second" asp-action="AddSecond">
            <table  style="border-spacing: 12px;">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Enter Seconds</strong></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="Seconds" class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Convert Second In Minutes</button></td>
                    <td>You have Entered-<strong>@ViewBag.Minutes</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

**`Output:`**

[image]